# Creating n quarter ahead date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have following date object

```
import datetime as datetime
import pandas as pd
Date = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 31, 0, 0))
```

Now I want to create another date which is `5 quarters` ahead from `Date`.

Is there any direct method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(pd.Period(Date, freq='Q')+5).to_timestamp()
```

```
Timestamp('2001-04-01 00:00:00')
```

to make it end of month

```
(pd.Period(Date, freq='Q')+5).to_timestamp(freq='M')
```

```
Timestamp('2001-04-30 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Many thanks. Is it possible to report the last day of the quarter, because the initial date `Date` is last day of January

Comment: updated the solution